# ¿Cómo puedo buscar un valor en cualquier campo de cualquier tabla de una base de datos?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la necesidad de buscar un valor de tipo texto pero no se en que tabla podría estar almacenado, por ello me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de buscar en todas las estructuras existentes dentro de una misma base de datos en SQL.

De repente se podría existe algún comando o se podría crear un store procedure que pueda hacer este tipo de trabajo de manera general.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796506/search-all-tables-all-columns-for-a-specific-value-sql-server

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Con este procedimiento almacenado podrás buscar en toda la BD.

```
CREATE PROC BuscaValorEnBBDD
(
@StrValorBusqueda nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #Resultado (NombreColumna nvarchar(370), ValorColumna nvarchar(3630))
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @NombreTabla nvarchar(256),
@NombreColumna nvarchar(128),
@StrValorBusqueda2 nvarchar(110)

SET  @NombreTabla = ''
SET @StrValorBusqueda2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @StrValorBusqueda + '%','''')

WHILE @NombreTabla IS NOT NULL
     BEGIN
     SET @NombreColumna = ''
     SET @NombreTabla =
     (SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
     WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
     AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @NombreTabla
     AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
     OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0)

     WHILE (@NombreTabla IS NOT NULL) AND (@NombreColumna IS NOT NULL)
         BEGIN
         SET @NombreColumna =
         (SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
         WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@NombreTabla, 2)
         AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@NombreTabla, 1)
         AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
         AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @NombreColumna)

         IF @NombreColumna IS NOT NULL
              BEGIN
              INSERT INTO #Resultado
              EXEC
              ('SELECT ''' + @NombreTabla + '.' + @NombreColumna + ''', LEFT(' + @NombreColumna + ', 3630)
              FROM ' + @NombreTabla + ' (NOLOCK) ' + ' WHERE ' + @NombreColumna + ' LIKE ' + @StrValorBusqueda2)
              END 
         END
     END
     SELECT NombreColumna, ValorColumna FROM #Resultado
END
```

Lo ejecutas de la siguiente forma:

```
EXEC dbo.BuscaValorEnBBDD 'texto'
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias Ariel, ahora mismo lo pruebo y te comento.

Comment: Ya hice la prueba, funcionó perfectamente a la primera pero luego me dijo que no se podía crear nuevamente la tabla **#Resultado** asi que le aumenté un **Drop Table #Resultado** y listo.
Nuevamente muchas gracias Ariel por tu ayuda.

Comment: @JuanManuelPalacios, sólo para aclarar y aunque no tiene que ver con la pregunta, lo que comentas te sucedió porque seguramente ejecutaste el código del SP por fuera, es decir el ámbito de la tabla temporal creada era global y no terminaba al finalizar el SP, igual no es mala idea agregar la sentencia que comentas al final del SP. éxitos.

Answer (score 2):

> Fuente y créditos: [SQL SERVER – Query to Find Column From All Tables
>   of Database](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/06/sql-server-query-to-find-column-from-all-tables-of-database/)

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%EmployeeID%' -- Aquí colocas el nombre de la columna que deseas buscar.
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Reemplaza "EmployeeID" por el nombre de la columna que deseas buscar.

Comment: En si esta respuesta no contesta la pregunta original, pero es muy buen método en lo que hace

Comment: @Nightmerker tiene usted razón :)