# Buscar Valor un valor en todas las tablas de base de datos

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Antes cuando trabajaba con unas 100 tablas en la base de datos hacía uso de un procedimiento almacenado proporcionado por la comunidad: [Buscar Valor en Base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/5947/193364).

```
CREATE PROC BuscaValorEnBBDD
(
@StrValorBusqueda nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #Resultado (NombreColumna nvarchar(370), ValorColumna nvarchar(3630))
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @NombreTabla nvarchar(256),
@NombreColumna nvarchar(128),
@StrValorBusqueda2 nvarchar(110)

SET  @NombreTabla = ''
SET @StrValorBusqueda2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @StrValorBusqueda + '%','''')

WHILE @NombreTabla IS NOT NULL
     BEGIN
     SET @NombreColumna = ''
     SET @NombreTabla =
     (SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
     WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
     AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @NombreTabla
     AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
     OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0)

     WHILE (@NombreTabla IS NOT NULL) AND (@NombreColumna IS NOT NULL)
         BEGIN
         SET @NombreColumna =
         (SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
         WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@NombreTabla, 2)
         AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@NombreTabla, 1)
         AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
         AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @NombreColumna)

         IF @NombreColumna IS NOT NULL
              BEGIN
              INSERT INTO #Resultado
              EXEC
              ('SELECT ''' + @NombreTabla + '.' + @NombreColumna + ''', LEFT(' + @NombreColumna + ', 3630)
              FROM ' + @NombreTabla + ' (NOLOCK) ' + ' WHERE ' + @NombreColumna + ' LIKE ' + @StrValorBusqueda2)
              END 
         END
     END
     SELECT NombreColumna, ValorColumna FROM #Resultado
END
```

Ahora que dispongo de 800 tablas en la base de datos, al ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado, me manda el siguiente error después de ejecutar:
**Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '].[CODIGO'.Severity 15**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenté ejecutar el código, lo analicé, pero no encuentro donde pueda estar el error. Lo ideal sería que capturaras la instrucción que estás realizando. Podrías imprimirla en pantalla y validar la última instrucción.

Comment: @LuisCazares la instrucción ejecutada es: **exec BuscaValorEnBBDD 'Valor a buscar'**, como explicaba en la pregunta, con pocas tablas no me genera error, pero ahora que cuento con unas 800 tablas se genera el error, talvéz el código se pueda mejorar y por ello la falla a consultas en una base de datos con muchas tablas.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que aumentes el tamaño de las variables. Pero el error no ayuda mucho.

Comment: @LuisCazares, es cierto el error no ayuda mucho pero es el único error que puedo mostrar ya que no hay más.

Comment: es el nombre de una tabla... trata de ir guardando los nombres a ver cual falla... es el de la tabla o uno de los campos... no es la cantidad...

Answer (score 0):

Yo preparé hace un tiempo un script para ese tipo de búsqueda que funciona en entornos de más de 2000 tablas. Eso sí, no es rápido, solo para búsquedas de emergencia:

```
-- Busca @src en todas las tablas con datos de la BD
declare @src varchar(128) = 'buscado'
set nocount on
declare @sql varchar(512), @tn sysname, @cn sysname, @sn sysname
declare @tbl table (tn sysname, cn sysname)
declare @tb1 table (sn sysname, tn sysname) -- tablas no vacías
set @sql = 'select s.name sn, t.name tn from sys.tables t '
         + 'join sys.schemas s on (s.schema_id = t.schema_id) '
         + 'join sys.partitions p on t.object_id=p.object_id and p.index_id in (0,1) '
         + 'group by s.name,t.name having sum(p.rows)>0'
insert @tb1 exec (@sql)
declare c1 cursor fast_forward for
    select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    join @tb1 t on t.tn = c.TABLE_NAME and t.sn = c.TABLE_SCHEMA
    where DATA_TYPE like '%char'
        and (CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH < 0 or CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH >= len(@src))
    order by 1,2,c.ORDINAL_POSITION
open c1
fetch next from c1 into @sn, @tn, @cn
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @sql='if exists(select top 1 1 from '+case @sn when 'dbo' then '' else '['+@sn+'].' end
            +'['+@tn+'] where ['+@cn+'] like ''%'+@src+'%'') select '''
            +case @sn when 'dbo' then '' else @sn+'.' end+@tn+''','''+@cn+''''
    insert @tbl exec (@sql)
    fetch next from c1 into @sn, @tn, @cn
end
close c1 deallocate c1
select * from @tbl
```